# Create Table from Tree

Tags: vba, excel

Given a tree like in the first image (where column number represents the depth in the tree) how can I convert it into a table like in the second image?

(Each row of the table contains the content of the tree's leaves, not the letter in the example.)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Are there any fixed parameters in this case? Is the last letter always Z, or are there more?

Comment: There are no fixed parameters, as long as i add data in the tree it should be generated into the table.

Comment: You can get halfway with `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:D9)`, which will give you a comma-separated string like `"A,B,C,D,G,E,H,F,I,J,K,N,L,O,M,P"`. Then it's just a matter of using something like Text-to-Columns (or `Split` in VBA) and then transposing into a column.

Comment: Or use a combination of `Left()` and `Right()` using the row number as a guide to step through your list @ashleedawg

Comment: @Luuklag - Good plan - I look forward to seeing what you come up with.  ;)

Comment: I'm not understanding the rules here.  When is something listed on the next row?  Why are D & G on the same row but A & B are not?  or a closer comparison why are C, D, G not on the same row but J, K, N are.  Also the the "C series" indicates that direct children are evaluated first C -> D, E, F...  If that's the case should B -> C, J not be evaluated first ?  @ashleedawg From my understanding of the expected output your string should read "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P"  DEF [4,4,4] is returned before GHI [5,5,5]

Comment: @JosephC The priority is set by column, so DEF are all higher priority than GHI. I do agree that it seems transposed compared to what makes sense, though, lol

Comment: My approach would be to go: loop cols, loop rows, transpose each slice between values

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 but if priority is set by columns then then J should have priority over DEF GHI and the output would always be sequential 1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5 ... no?  J being a child of B, sibling of C.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll show here how I'm looking at it (this is only sort of an answer).

If you can group it into "blocks" based on the space between the "largest" nodes in the tree, then you can just transpose each block and then they're sorted and you can get your output by looping through it the standard way and noting the row numbers.

[image: examples]

Reading along the rows in example 1 gives us:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,    (grouping one)
3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5           (grouping two)
```

Which should match the list you have above as your expected output

Comment: It's an interesting approach.  Rule set seems to be something like: Evaluate siblings first, except if you have more than one child (then evaluate children in order of parents).  I think we would need more examples from the original poster, like what if in example1 D had two children?

Comment: In example 2, ABK are siblings, but A B are together in the output and K listed much later.  Where as DEF are siblings and they is listed first before any of their children.

Comment: @JosephC yeah and even if this gets untangled, it'd be kind of a beast to program this haha. I added numbers to the picture and slightly more to the explanation

Comment: lol... Good stuff though  :)  I was initially considering a recursive approach. :p

Comment: @JosephC yeah I thought about it but was having trouble with he edge cases for it, and I was starting to feel like I had sunk too much time into this problem’s “design” lol